# Converting string with leading zero into integer

Tags: c#

I have a string `(string value="01")`, when i converting this string into int 
`(int tempValue= int.Parse(value))`. Then i am getting result=1.
I want this value same as string value, which is leading zero.

Answer:--

```
int length = 3;
int number = 20;
string asString = number.ToString("D" + length); //"020"
```

Comment: Numbers are represented as they are. string is an appropriate data type if you want to prefix it with 0.

Comment: A **numerical** value like `int` doesn't have and doesn't show leading zeroes. `1` numerically is identical to `01`

Comment: If you have to retain leading Zero, you have to deal with string type only. Its not possible to retain leading 0 as int type.

Comment: What's happening to StackOverflow?!

Answer (score 6):

According to arithmetics `01 == 1`, so the *integer itself* is **1**; if you want to *format out* integer back into *string* with leading zero, you can use appropriate *formatting*:

```
  int tempValue = 1;
  String back = tempValue.ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 4):

There's no such a thing like an integer with a leading zero. A `1` is just a `1`. You're talking about the representation of a value here.

So if you want to represent the integer value `1` with a leading zero, just format it accordingly using `String.Format`:

```
String.Format("{0:00}", 1)
```

---

In response to your comment:

If you don't want to use a certain format (like `00`) but rather always append a `0`, no matter how many digits, you can just prepend the `0` to the string, like `String.Format("0{0}", 1)` or `"0" + 1`.

---

In response to your second comment:

So basically you want that the result to have as many digits as the input (which is a number as string with any number of leading zeros)? Then you should use `PadLeft`.

```
string input = "001";
string output = (int.Parse(input) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(input.Length, '0');
```

`output` is now `"002"`.

Comment: I am not sure that string has only {0:00} format. It can be {0:000} , {0:0000}

Comment: If you don't want to use a certain format (like `00`) but rather *always* append a `0`, no matter how many digits, you can just prepend the `0` to the string, like `String.Format("0{0}", 1)` or `"0" + 1`

Comment: please see below example as per your answer:-                                             `string value="001";
string tempvalue = String.Format("0{0}", (int.Parse(value) + 1));`      in this case i am getting '02' but i want to get '002'.

Comment: So basically you want that the result to have as many digits as the input (which is a number as string with any number of leading zeros)? Then you should use `PadLeft`. See my update.

Comment: int length = 3;
int number = 20;
string asString = number.ToString("D" + length); //"020"

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do that**. As, An int is represent of mathematical integer.

Answer (score 1):

The leading zero's for an integer are irrelevant.  `01` is the same as `1`.

If you want to show a leading zero when *formatting an integer as a string*, use something similar to:

```
myInteger.ToString("00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ONLY use string datatype to handle this scenario. For leading/trailing zeros we have [string.PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [string.PadRight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) functions available.

Answer (score 0):

```
int length = 3;
int number = 20;
string asString = number.ToString("D" + length); //"020"
```

Comment: It's the same code of your question. How this could be a solution?

Comment: see here it cann't have dependancy means you can use it any format of string when u don't know about string format